# Using LaTeX in posts creates superfluous | symbols

Tags: support, status-completed, mathjax

I found that using LaTeX on profile/posts on my profile there is '|' in last of every line. Can you help me to correct these error, please?

Comment: Do you have this problem on all posts on the site or only on some of them, and what about other sites such as [math.se]? What browser are you using (and what exact version), under what operating system? Do you have the same problem in an incognito or private browsing window? Are you using any extension, add-on, etc. that could have an influence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug I have been having for the last 2-3 days. It happens with all MathJax rendering, not just in a profile. The culprit must be a browser addon, because when I start a new, clean, browser profile, I don't see it.

I have not yet looked into it to see which addon is causing the problem. I am inclined to suspect LastPass, because it was updated soon before I noticed it.

Comment: Yes, when I cleaned browser's cache, it fixed now. Thanks for help.

Comment: only the cache? That's very interesting, will have to try it when I get to the computer where it appears.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use MathJax in your profile. It won't work on sites without MathJax, e.g. [Meta](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31126/mithlesh-upadhyay?tab=profile). Also, nobody wants to see colorful markup in your description.
2. I have looked at your profile and some of your posts. I can not see any '|'s there. Please provide a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.